# UIView not updating even though it's value appears to be changed within the code

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to update a UIView (a pie chart) with a new value.  In the below method I successfully set the UIView's `pieChart.counter` value to what I want (and I print it out to test it), but the pie chart view doesn't update with this value for some reason.

```
//MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pieChart: CounterView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

var healthData = HealthData()
let counterView = CounterView()
var scoreInt = 0 

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.healthData.updateHealthCharacteristics()
    let seconds = 0.1
    let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
    let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.scoreInt = Int(self.healthData.score)
        self.scoreLabel.text = String(self.scoreInt)
        self.counterView.counter = self.scoreInt
        self.pieChart.counter = self.counterView.counter
        print("pieChartValue: ", self.pieChart.counter)
        let dateString = self.formatDate(self.yesterday!)
        self.dateLabel.text = String(dateString)
    })
}
```

In the class that I draw the pie chart, I have this code:

```
@IBDesignable class CounterView: UIView {

  let possiblePoints = 100
  let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

  @IBInspectable var outlineColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()
  @IBInspectable var counterColor: UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

  var counter: Int = 0

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    print("foo")
  }
}
```

I've tested the `drawRect` method, and it works fine, however it doesn't seem to be firing when I try to update `pieChart.counter` using the instance of `CounterView` I created in my viewController.

Comment: First thing, you do `super.viewDidLoad` in `viewWillAppear:` method. Although I don't think it is the reason, but can you check it anyway, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redraw some view you just have to call `setNeedsDisplay` on it. See [Drawing Concepts in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html) for more information on what can trigger a redraw.